# What does it mean: "to write in large box letters"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

in this sentence:
ask everyone to write in large box letters.

Comment: It's simply a different term for "block letters" -- plain, non-script, san-serif capital letters.  This was a common term when I was in elementary school, but seems to have passed out of fashion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the term.  I think it might just be badly written - perhaps they mean "large block capital letters"?  I could see how "block" could get mistranslated to "box", since "block" is another word for "rectangle", which in turn could be called a "box".

"Block capitals" is a style of writing which just uses clearly written capital letters, well spaced out, perhaps for machine reading.  It's a common requirement for filling out forms.

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/block-capitals